# MediaPlayer jumps to last seekTo() position

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-seekbar

When I call seekTo() method on the media player the file is played from the correct location and it works well but once the playback is done I expect it to return to "0", instead it returns to the location from where I called the seekTo() method.

I'm using a thread that samples the current position every 500ms and then update my SeekBar with progress. Since the mediaPlayer is going back to the last place I "seeked" - the Seekbar is jumping back to there and it looks bad.

I want it to go back to 0 location once the file is done playing which of course I can set it manually using the OnCompletionListener but this creates a jump to the location I set using seekTo() method and then back to 0.

Here is my code for the progress sampling I'm making:

```
private void updateProgress() {
    mListenerThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (isRunning) {
                int position = mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
                mProgressListener.onProgress(position);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    mMediaPlayer.seekTo(0);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });
    mListenerThread.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could save that position that has been set and check if the current position is the set position and if so, set the progress to zero which would stop the jump from happening on OnCompletionListener

Define a variable

```
int lastSeek = -1;
```

and when seeking set it to the position that has been seeked to

```
void seekTo(int position) {
 //do the seeking here
 lastSeek = position;
}
```

then on updateProgress you would see if position is lastSeek and if so the position is 0 aka

```
private void updateProgress() {
    mListenerThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (isRunning) {
                int position = mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
                mProgressListener.onProgress(position == lastSeek ? 0 : position);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    mMediaPlayer.seekTo(0);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });
    mListenerThread.start();
}
```

and in onCompletionListener just set lastSeek to -1

```
MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener completionListener
                      = new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener(){    
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
     lastSeek = -1;
     //set actual position to zero and update the bar
   }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Please implement onCompletion Listener .

```
mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
```

When song is ended then media player automatically called onCompletion method.

```
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) 
    {
        // Write your code
// Here, set the seekTo to 0 like this seekTo(0);
    }
```

Comment: OP mentioned that onCompletion listener would make the bar jump temporarily to the position set on last seek

Comment: Of course I'm listening to this callback and actually setting in it, the Seekbar view to progress 0 manually. but the mediaplayer alone jumps to last seek position so the user actually see a jump - to last seek and then - to 0